# Enlazar una variable de Componente a la directiva styles en Angular

Tags: css, angular

Estoy trabajando en **Angular 4** pero estoy atascado. Digamos que tengo una clase CSS llamada `cover-art`:

```
.cover-art {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background-color: rojo;
}
```

Y luego quiero actualizar esa clase a través de entradas en la plantilla HTML. No quiero modificar directamente `<div class="cover-art">` pero quiero cambiar los valores en la directiva styles o sobrescribir esa clase.

Estaba pensando en crear una clase CSS en la clase de definición de componentes y vincularlo con `@HostBinding` o algo así, pero no sé ... Tal vez no es posible.

No quiero usar jQuery u otra biblioteca, no tiene sentido hacer eso.

Comment: Buenas, tu idea es modificar la clase para que afecte a todos los componentes que la tengan? Y que esa modificación a la clase se mantenga hasta que alguna otra acción la vuelva a modificar? O solo modificar algo temporalmente en una sola vista?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,

Hay muchas formas de hacer eso en Angular y es realmente sencillo.

Tienes NgClass, el cual le puedes dar una clase que previamente hayas definido en tu hoja de estilo.

> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

También tienes NgStyle, parecido al anterior pero con estilos en línea.

> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgStyle-directive.html

Hay otras formas pero creo que para lo que buscas, estas serian las mas indicadas.

PS: Incluso si tienes que capturar elementos del DOM, **no hay razón que justifique el uso de jQuery**, puedes hacerlo con TS, es un consejo :)

*Otro link para ejemplos:*

> https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-classes-with-ngclass-and-ngstyle

Comment: Es que en ambos casos (NgClass y NgStyle) tendría que intervenir la plantilla HTML y lo que yo quiero es modificar una clase CSS, no la etiqueta HTML en sí.

Comment: Intervernir la plantilla HTML? no entiendo a qué te refieres. La etiqueta HTML no la cambias solo añades estilo, no su contenido, si eso no te vale, siento decirte que lo que pretendes hacer no es posible, no puedes modifcar el css de una clase ya asignada con angular, ni tampoco deberías.